# Парсирование приложения HP

Tags: winapi, delphi

> Все мы знаем что в оконном
> системе(Windows) все элементы
> являються
> окнами(кнопки,мемо,радиокнопки и тд).
> Так вот,есть такой элемент Toolbar(в
> чужой программе),естественно у нее
> только 1 ИД номер(скажем $0004F4AA), и
> в этом Тоолбар-е 2 кнопки)))),думаю
> это через Items сделали. А Spy++ даже
> не хочеть этих кнопок
> показывать,возможно из за
> родительского окна (Тоолбар). Как
> дотянуться к "кнопкам"?)))
>
> Пытаюсь получить хэндл окна приложений
> принтера и нажать на нем кнопку
> "Обновить"(без названия). В `Мемо1`
> вижу список элементов "Состояние",
> "Состояние расходных материалов", "HP
> LaserJetp2255" и т .д. Не могу
> получить доступ к кнопке "Обновить".
> Помогите, плиз!

*ScreenShot:http://rghost.ru/31364881/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи программы Spy++ можно определить, какое сообщение посылает кнопка окну при нажатии. Посылаешь этому окну от своей программы сообщение WM_COMMAND с параметрами, выясненными в программе и кнопка нажата! Точнее, графически ты не увидишь, что кнопка нажата, просто выполнится код этой кнопки. Только не знаю, есть ли Spy++ у тебя? Она входит в состав Visual Studio, а насчёт Delphi не знаю.

Comment: Сорри,плиз,не могу нажать лев. кнопку мыши пробовал эти варианты:t,pr:Thandle;
PostMessage(t,VK_LBUTTON,0,MakeLParam(35,18));
PostMessage(pr2,WM_MOUSEMOVE,StrToInt(Edit1.text),StrToInt(Edit2.text));
PostMessage(pr,WM_SETCURSOR,StrToInt(Edit1.text),StrToInt(Edit2.text));
PostMessage(pr,WM_MOUSEMOVE,1,MakeLParam(StrToInt(Edit1.text),StrToInt(Edit2.text))); PostMessage(pr,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,MakeLParam(StrToInt(Edit1.text),StrToInt(Edit2.text)));
  PostMessage(pr,WM_LBUTTONUP,WM_LBUTTONUP,MakeLParam(StrToInt(Edit1.text),StrToInt(Edit2.text)));

Comment: Не понял, причём тут левая кнопка мыши? Окну нужно посылать сообщение WM_COMMAND.